# Want the same result in Python with using TINV in Excel

Tags: python, excel

> a= 0.05
> b= 10.8

the result in excel TINV(a,b) is 2.228138852

```
from scipy import stats
```

`result = stats.t.ppf(1 - a, b)`

the result is 1.7989330052096262

How I can get the same result in Python what I get by using TINV in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 factors you need to know. First of all, in Excel [TINV Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/tinv-function-a7c85b9d-90f5-41fe-9ca5-1cd2f3e1ed7c) truncates the number of degrees of freedom (source: Microsoft)

> If deg_freedom is not an integer, it is truncated.

So in Excel doing `TINV(0.05 , 10.8)` and `TINV(0.05 , 10)` will return the same value.

Second factor, Excel TINV function returns the **two-tailed** inverse of the Student's t-distribution. But in Python, you are using only 1 tail:

> [How to Find the T Critical Value in
> Python](https://www.statology.org/how-to-find-the-t-critical-value-in-python/)

So you need to do `a/2`. In Python you could do then:

```
from scipy import stats
a= 0.05
b= 10 # Integer because Excel truncates degrees of freedom
result = stats.t.ppf(1-a/2, b)
print(result)

2.2281388519649385
```

As you can see, the ouput `2.2281388519649385` is pretty close to what you get on Excel `2,22813884242587` Not the same (I don't know why, I guess it's a decimal issue) but pretty close.

Comment: Yean，I use int(b) instead of b,more close,but still not clear!

Comment: @Jonas-2020 What do you mean not clear? The results are almost the same, actually the first 7 decimals are the same. The difference could be maybe just because Excel works with a different quantity of decimals than Python.